# Как импортировать sql файл из mysql в MS sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

У меня есть файд .sql из mysql мне уго надо импортировать в database от microsoft sql server.
Я пытался через ms sql managment но когда я нажимаю выполнить у меня ошибка

Comment: думаете тут телепаты все и догадаются сами что у вас в файле, и что за ошибка? Диалект mysql и mssql различается. Что у вас в файле то DDL или DML, или оба? Открывайте в SSMS исправляйте синтаксис.

Comment: Скорее всего ` левый апостоф надо заменить на правый ' . Обьявление таблиц - похоже (но нету innodb и msiasm). Типы совпадают не все. Индексы - переписать.

Comment: Малореально, если .SQL - это дамп. Там слишком много MySQL-специфичного хлама. Я бы рекомендовал поставить MySQL-сервер, включая ODBC4MySQL, загрузить туда дамп, а потом перегнать данные на MS SQL с использованием OpenRowSet.